# Creating fields in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-table

I am making a quiz portal and for that I am having a quiz table. Here I am saving the quiz id , quiz questions and quiz answers.

Now I am confused in the quiz answers part.

My question has 4 options so should I make 4 columns for four options, or should I make a comma separated list of 4 options and save in one column? Which will be the better choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never store multiple values in a single column!

One way would be

```
questions table
---------------
id
quiz_id
title

answers table
-------------
id
question_id
answer_text
```

That way a question can have as many answers as you like.

Comment: actually creating separate tables are leading to join queries while fetching . So join queries make the performance slow , so was thinking of comma separated String.

Comment: That is nonsense. JOINS are the way to go and they don't make things slow.